# How do you use importlib to load <directory path>/__init__.py

Tags: python, python-importlib

I have the following directory structure

```
Sub
   trackers
       __init__.py
```

Given

```
bundle_path = "<path>/Sub"
```

I want to use import lib to load the `__init_.py` file from `trackers`. I'm aware that I can move files around so I have another file structure to "fix" my problem, but I'm aiming to do dynamic import, not explicit.

I've tried variations of spec_from_file_location, but it doesn't seem to get a loader assigned.

Is there a recommended way?

The following doesn't work:

```
        spec = util.spec_from_file_location('__init__', self.bundle_path.joinpath('trackers'))
        module = util.module_from_spec(spec)
        spec.loader.exec_module(module)
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the fix was simple. Past failures to arrive at this may have been due to other import machinery going bad inside the loaded code.

```
spec = util.spec_from_file_location('trackers', self.bundle_path.joinpath('trackers', '__init__.py'))
        module = util.module_from_spec(spec)
        spec.loader.exec_module(module)
```

Did the trick.